# How to setup SSH keys for buildbot user

Tags: linux, git, ssh, buildbot

I'm trying to setup SSH keys for Buildbot's buildbot user, so it can clone my private repo without needing a username and password.

This is how I'm testing:

```
sudo -u buildbot bash
export HOME=/var/lib/buildbot
cd $HOME
mkdir git
cd git
git clone git@bitbucket.org:myproject/myrepo.git
```

the last step fails with:

```
Cloning into 'myrepo'...
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Why am I getting this error? I've confirmed my SSH key is correct with:

1. `/var/lib/buildbot/.ssh` folder exists with the correct permissions
2. `/var/lib/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa` file exists with the correct permissions
3. `/var/lib/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file exists with the correct permissions
4. the content of `/var/lib/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` file has been registered in my Bitbucket account as my SSH key

If I run:

```
ssh-agent bash -c 'ssh-add /var/lib/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa; git clone git@bitbucket.org:myproject/myrepo.git'
```

then it clones my repo perfectly. Why isn't the normal command able to access my SSH key?

Edit: The output of `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org` is:

```
OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1, OpenSSL 1.0.2g  1 Mar 2016
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 19: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "bitbucket.org" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to bitbucket.org [104.192.143.2] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ecdsa type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1
debug1: key_load_public: No such file or directory
debug1: identity file /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_7.2p2 Ubuntu-4ubuntu2.1
debug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote software version conker_1.0.288-e9ef8ea app-123
debug1: no match: conker_1.0.288-e9ef8ea app-123
debug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK
debug1: Authenticating to bitbucket.org:22 as 'git'
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa
debug3: send packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent
debug3: receive packet: type 20
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received
debug2: local client KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha1,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,ext-info-c
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,ssh-ed25519
debug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com,aes128-cbc,aes192-cbc,aes256-cbc,3des-cbc
debug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1
debug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal
debug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1,diffie-hellman-group1-sha1
debug2: host key algorithms: ssh-dss,ssh-rsa
debug2: ciphers ctos: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: ciphers stoc: aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,arcfour256,arcfour128
debug2: MACs ctos: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: MACs stoc: hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha1,hmac-sha1-96
debug2: compression ctos: none
debug2: compression stoc: none
debug2: languages ctos: 
debug2: languages stoc: 
debug2: first_kex_follows 0 
debug2: reserved 0 
debug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org
debug1: kex: host key algorithm: ssh-rsa
debug1: kex: server->client cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug1: kex: client->server cipher: aes128-ctr MAC: hmac-sha2-256 compression: none
debug3: send packet: type 30
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY
debug3: receive packet: type 31
debug1: Server host key: ssh-rsa SHA256:zzXQOXSRBEiUtuE8AikJYKwbHaxvSc0ojez9YXaGp1A
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from bitbucket.org
debug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts"
debug3: record_hostkey: found key type RSA in file /home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts:2
debug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 104.192.143.2
debug1: Host 'bitbucket.org' is known and matches the RSA host key.
debug1: Found key in /home/buildbot/.ssh/known_hosts:1
debug3: send packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 1
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS
debug3: receive packet: type 21
debug2: set_newkeys: mode 0
debug1: rekey after 4294967296 blocks
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received
debug2: key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_dsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ecdsa ((nil))
debug2: key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ed25519 ((nil))
debug3: send packet: type 5
debug3: receive packet: type 6
debug2: service_accept: ssh-userauth
debug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received
debug3: send packet: type 50
debug3: receive packet: type 51
debug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey
debug3: start over, passed a different list publickey
debug3: preferred gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,publickey,keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_lookup publickey
debug3: remaining preferred: keyboard-interactive,password
debug3: authmethod_is_enabled publickey
debug1: Next authentication method: publickey
debug1: Trying private key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_rsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_dsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_dsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ecdsa
debug3: no such identity: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ecdsa: No such file or directory
debug1: Trying private key: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ed25519
debug3: no such identity: /home/buildbot/.ssh/id_ed25519: No such file or directory
debug2: we did not send a packet, disable method
debug1: No more authentication methods to try.
Permission denied (publickey).
```

Edit: Updating buildbot's home directory in `/etc/passwd` to point to `/var/lib/buildbot` causes more problems. Now I can't even access buildbot's home directory as buildbot:

```
$ sudo -u buildbot bash
$ echo $HOME
/home/ubuntu
$ export HOME=/var/lib/buildbot
$ cd $HOME
bash: cd: /var/lib/buildbot: Permission denied
```

Comment: post the debug log from `ssh -vvv git@bitbucket.org`

Comment: @Jakuje, I've updated the post.

Comment: And how did it work before if the only thing you changed was the home directory in passwd? The user does not have there permissions or is there some other factor (SELinux?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OpenSSH is not using environment variable `$HOME`, as you can see from the log, but uses directly the [`getpwnam()`](https://github.com/openssh/openssh-portable/blob/master/misc.c#L605) functions to get the real home directory of running user (`/home/buildbot/`).

You either have to fix it in `/etc/passwd` or use the `ssh-agent` or `IdentityFile` option/config value to the `ssh` to make `ssh` use this key.

Answer (score 3):

Buildbot now supports specifying private SSH keys (these changes will be released as part of buildbot 1.3.0). See https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/4178 and https://github.com/buildbot/buildbot/pull/4160

Disclaimer: I'm the author of these PRs :-)